# how to save fixed line call log to database

Tags: c#, java, c#-3.0

I am going to develop a client side application such a way that my client should able to receive fixed line calls through a computer and the application which is running on client's machine able to save the caller's number to a remote database.

Is there any application currently available for this? What are the requirements should I have before begin the project?

Comment: You may want to look at Asterisk PBX.

Comment: are you saying you want to write a program that logs caller id of a softphone? or do you want to write the whole telephony platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably have to setup a PBX system in your client computer if you are wishing to connect phone line to the computer. You'll have to buy a Terminal and input a SIM to it. Or you could buy a SIP trunk from a Service provider and you'll able to take calls via the Internet.

If you are connecting with Java you'll have to use Asterisk PBX API and some configurations are necessary inside the PBX system. For logging calls to the remote database would be easier since Asterisk can be configured to store Calls to a MYSQL database.

As for more customization of this process would require a remote database and manual logging.

If you are going to use the Asterisk API you will find it quite helpful since you can take calls directly using it. But if it's for a simple use you can go ahead and install a Softphone - something like X-Lite or Linphone.

You can refer [this tutorial](http://www.asterisk-java.org/development/tutorial.html) for more use of Asterisk Java.